# Re-using same TCP port for Python socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, port

I have been using TCP socket communication in Python and I am stumbled upon such a problem on which I cannot find a direct answer anywhere. I want to re-use the exact same python socket server with the same port. I found several question threads and documents regarding `SO_REUSEADDR` but none of them helps. Below is my python server which I want to reuse:

```
import socket
import numpy as np

TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
TCP_PORT = 5003

BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
from can import Message

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()

while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    datalist = list(data)
    print("received data: %s" % datalist)
    print(data)
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

So here I want to use this exact same script with `5003` port again. Also do I need to make any changes in my client script?

Please if anyone can advise on this, will really appreciate.

Comment: You need to close the server socket as soon as you're not going to accept any more connections. Then, SO_REUSEADDR will allow you to listen on the same port even though there's already a client connected. It won't let you listen with more than one server at the same time! But most people would make a server that can handle more than one connection

Comment: Doesn't `conn.close()` close it? If not then how can I close it?

Comment: You have two sockets: s, and conn. s is waiting for new connections. You can't have two sockets at the same time on the same port that are waiting for new connections (even with SO_REUSEADDR).

Comment: @FarhanKabir Making the receive buffer smaller doesn't make anything faster.

Comment: Ok understood. In that case, I should add `s.close()`

Comment: Okay so adding `s.close()` allows me to use the same port number at a different python script. But it does not allow me to re-use the exact same python script again. I want to use the same server script again.